# Can i lookup an environment variable for netbox inventory plugin

Tags: ansible

I've been using the netbox dynamic inventory plugin a lot recently, but want to make it a bit more consumable for my other team members.  The config for the plugin looks like:

```
plugin: netbox
api_endpoint: http://our-netbox-server.com
validate_certs: False
config_context: False
token: abc123 

group_by:
  - device_roles

query_filters:
  - role: tor-switch
  - role: something
  - role: something_else
```

I was hoping i could lookup the `token` section from my environment variables, so something like:

`token: "{{ lookup('env', 'NETBOX_TOKEN') }}"`

however this doesn't work at all.  Anyone got any suggestions around how i can make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use the community inventory plugin from https://github.com/netbox-community/ansible_modules. This already supports the environment variables. So the token and API endpoint does not need to be stored in the configuration.

```
api_endpoint:
    description: Endpoint of the NetBox API
    required: True
    env:
        - name: NETBOX_API
        
token:
    required: False
    description:
      - NetBox API token to be able to read against NetBox.
      - This may not be required depending on the NetBox setup.
    env:
      # in order of precedence
      - name: NETBOX_TOKEN
      - name: NETBOX_API_KEY
```